# How to add one SBT project as a dependency of another?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following project setup:

```
Base/
  build.sbt
  src/

Main/
  build.sbt
  src/
```

Where `Base` and `Main` are two projects. I would like `Main` to have the classes of `Base` on the classpath of `Main`. If possible, I would like to keep the builds separate. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Multi-Project build, maybe it will be best in you case: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html

However if this two projects are completely separate sbt supports source dependencies, it definitely works with github and I think should work with file dependencies as well

```
lazy val Main = Project("Main", file("."), settings = ...) dependsOn(baseDep)

lazy val baseDep = uri("file:///path/to/base/project")
```

Comment: That's awesome. For the file path, where should that point to exactly?

Comment: You can read more about github dependencies here: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/using-github-projects-scala-library-dependencies-sbt-sbteclipse

Comment: It worked, I pointed the URI the root directory of the project.

Comment: To future reader - URL mentioned in the answer points to now deprecated version of SBT. Here is the latest URL for the same page https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html

(chances are that this URL will also get deprecated after couple of years)